# Menu does not appear in reduced window size / responsive, using ibm carbon design system

Tags: carbon-design-system

Where should i change to make sure the Menu appears in all window / screen sizes of a website?

Built site using https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-angular-starter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution

1. Add the below line to `/src/styles.scss` file

```
...

@import "./assets/scss/carbon-override.scss";
```

2. Add a new file `carbon-override.scss` to `/src/assets/scss`

```
// forces the navigation items to be displayed at all viewport sizes
.bx--header__nav {
    display: block;
}
```

PR/code on [github](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-angular-starter/pull/32).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this open issue in Carbon/Carbon-Angular:

https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-angular/issues/1140

Comment: and https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-angular-starter/issues/30

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, but it explains the problem and points you at the place to get the issue fixed correctly (i.e. the Carbon-Angular team).